# Couldn't find User with id=search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I want to a searching function for users. It does not work. So I simplified the method, I just want to refresh the index page when I hit the search button. But it still does not work, it said 
**ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show, Couldn't find User with id=search.**

please tell me Why

my controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController   
     load_and_authorize_resource    :except => [:index]


 def search
    redirect_to users_path   
 end


end
```

My view

```
   <%= form_tag users_search_path, :method => 'get' do %>

  <td><%= text_field_tag :username, params[:username] %></td>

  <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => "buttons buttons-rounded buttons-flat-action", :id => "button-new"%>

  <br><br><br>
  <% end %>
```

My Route

```
  Procedures::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users


  #### USER MANAGEMENT ####
  resources :users do
  resources :rateofpays # professional timesheet
  resources :roles
  resources :biographies
  resources :qualifications do
    collection do
      put  'complete', :action => 'complete'
    end
  end
  resources :supervisors

  end
 #### users search ####
  get 'users/search' => "users#search", as: 'users_search'
```

Comment: Stack traces usually narrow down the problem significantly. Also try and post the minimal amount required to re-create the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
  get 'users/search' => "users#search", as: 'users_search'
```

...is too far down in your routes.  the `resources :users` appears first, and it has a match path that looks like `users/:id` and the `users/search` is incorrectly matching against that.

Just move the `get 'users/search'` to the top... or alternatively define it as a collection method under `resources :users`

```
resources :users do 
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :) If my answer has been helpful, you can 'accept' it (the option is just to the left of my answer where the vote up/down arrows are).

Comment: oK, But I do not have enough repution

Comment: ...to accept an answer? I thought you can't vote, but you could accept.  I could be wrong... stackoverflow rules always confuse me. :)

Comment: It should be a check box, I think.

Comment: Agreed - learning rails now, and this little fix saved a lot of confusion.